# En funciones de respuestas a callbacks, que llaman a su vez a otra, ¿ es correcto salir con setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

Es una cosa que hago habitualmente; por ejemplo, en esta *hipotética* función

```
function fetchData( url, args, callback, opts ) {
  var ajax = webix.ajax( );

  ...

  function success( text, data, xhr ) {
    var response;

    ...

    setTimeout( function( ) { callback( response ); }, 0 );
  }

  function failure( ) {
    var response;

    ...

    setTimeout( function( ) { callback( response ); }, 0 }
  }
}
```

Sería una función para realizar llamadas *AJAX*, comprobar los posibles errores, y devolver una salida en un formato común, tanto si hubo errores como si no.

Puesto que es una función que hace una llamada *AJAX*, es asíncrona. Por lo tanto, no puedo retornar directamente el valor, así que utilizo el argumento `callback`. Cuando tengo algo que devolver, llamo a esa función.

La lógica que he usado siempre es:

> Ya que Javascript está basado en eventos, y estos no se procesan mientras estemos ejecutando código, lo mejor es **terminar el código cuanto antes**.

Por ello, en lugar de hacer:

```
callback( response );
```

Que aumentaría el tiempo de **ejecución continuada** de mi código, hago esto otro:

```
setTimeout( function( ) { callback( response ); }, 0 );
```

Con lo cual, se crearía un evento en la cola para realizar la llamada a `callback( )`. Mi código Javascript termina, y el navegador puede seguir procesando sus *cositas*.

¿ Estoy en lo correcto al proceder así ? ¿ Hay algún posible efecto secundario oculto y que espera *agazapado* para atacarme en cualquier momento ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu planteamiento es correcto y no tiene pegas más allá de la sobrecarga en la cola de ejecución (que es despreciable), aunque generalmente no es necesario: Javascript no es el lenguaje más rápido del mundo, pero a menos que hagas cálculos muy pesados que consuman mucha CPU, como pueda ser el cifrado/descifrado de un texto muy largo, compresión/descompresión de archivos, tratamientos de imagen... no notarás mejora.

Hay un posible efecto secundario que podrías mitigar fácilmente, y que podrás ver con un ejemplo sencillo:

```js
$(function () {

  function callback() {
    console.log(this.id);
  }
  $('#btn1').click(callback);
  
  
  $('#btn2').click(function () {
    setTimeout(callback);
  });
  
  $('#btn3').click(function () {
    setTimeout(callback.bind(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Botón 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Botón 2</button>
<button id="btn3">Botón 3</button>
```

Como puedes observar, jQuery siempre llama a la función "callback" asegurando que el contexto es el elemento que ha recibido el evento, y éste se pierde al usar setTimeout a menos que lo fijes explícitamente.

**Conclusión**: los posibles efectos secundarios son mínimos y fácilmente evitables.

Una pregunta relacionada en SO en inglés, con una respuesta bastante completa, la puedes encontrar [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful/23747597#23747597)